# Query on same database runs in .4 seconds in mariadb and 83 seconds in mysql 5.6,5.7 and 8

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query that runs really slow on mysql (83 seconds) but really fast on mariadb (.4 seconds).

I verified the data database has the same indexes and data. Maria Db server has less cpu (1VCPU), memory (2gb)

Mysql servers have 8 - 32GB ram and full quad core processors (tried 5.6,5.7, and 8.0 with similar results).

The phppos_inventory table has ~170000 rows and the phppos_items table has ~3000 rows

Here is the query and the tables and explains

```
SELECT /*+ SEMIJOIN(@subq MATERIALIZATION) */ SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
1                                            AS _h, 
`phppos_location_items`.`location_id`        AS `location_id`, 
`phppos_items`.`item_id`, 
`phppos_items`.`name`, 
`phppos_categories`.`id`                     AS `category_id`, 
`phppos_categories`.`name`                   AS `category`, 
`location`, 
`company_name`, 
`phppos_items`.`item_number`, 
`size`, 
`product_id`, 
Coalesce(phppos_location_item_variations.cost_price, 
phppos_item_variations.cost_price, phppos_location_items.cost_price, 
phppos_items.cost_price, 0)                  AS cost_price, 
Coalesce(phppos_location_item_variations.unit_price, 
phppos_item_variations.unit_price, phppos_location_items.unit_price, 
phppos_items.unit_price, 0)                  AS unit_price, 
Sum(Coalesce(inv.trans_current_quantity, 0)) AS quantity, 
Coalesce(phppos_location_item_variations.reorder_level, 
phppos_item_variations.reorder_level, phppos_location_items.reorder_level, 
phppos_items.reorder_level)                  AS reorder_level, 
Coalesce(phppos_location_item_variations.replenish_level, 
phppos_item_variations.replenish_level, phppos_location_items.replenish_level, 
phppos_items.replenish_level)                AS replenish_level, 
description 
FROM   `phppos_inventory` `inv` 
       LEFT JOIN `phppos_items` 
              ON `phppos_items`.`item_id` = `inv`.`trans_items` 
       LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_items` 
              ON `phppos_location_items`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
                 AND `phppos_location_items`.`location_id` = `inv`.`location_id` 
       LEFT JOIN `phppos_item_variations` 
              ON `phppos_items`.`item_id` = `phppos_item_variations`.`item_id` 
                 AND `phppos_item_variations`.`id` = `inv`.`item_variation_id` 
                 AND `phppos_item_variations`.`deleted` = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_item_variations` 
              ON `phppos_location_item_variations`.`item_variation_id` = 
                           `phppos_item_variations`.`id` 
                 AND `phppos_location_item_variations`.`location_id` = 
                     `inv`.`location_id` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `phppos_suppliers` 
                    ON `phppos_items`.`supplier_id` = 
                       `phppos_suppliers`.`person_id` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `phppos_categories` 
                    ON `phppos_items`.`category_id` = `phppos_categories`.`id` 
WHERE  inv.trans_id = (SELECT Max(inv1.trans_id) 
                       FROM   phppos_inventory inv1 
                       WHERE  inv1.trans_items = inv.trans_items 
                              AND ( inv1.item_variation_id = 
                                    phppos_item_variations.id 
                                     OR phppos_item_variations.id IS NULL ) 
                              AND inv1.location_id = inv.location_id 
                              AND inv1.trans_date < '2019-12-31 23:59:59') 
       AND inv.location_id IN( 1 ) 
       AND `phppos_items`.`system_item` = 0 
       AND `phppos_items`.`deleted` = 0 
       AND `is_service` != 1 
GROUP  BY `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
LIMIT  20
```

Explain mysql (slighly different than maria db but I tried use index to match the execution plan and still was slow)

```
+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                           | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | key                     | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+---------------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_items                    | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,item_number,product_id,phppos_items_ibfk_1,deleted,phppos_items_ibfk_3,phppos_items_ibfk_4,phppos_items_ibfk_5,description,size,reorder_level,cost_price,unit_price,promo_price,last_modified,name,phppos_items_ibfk_6,deleted_system_item,custom_field_1_value,custom_field_2_value,custom_field_3_value,custom_field_4_value,custom_field_5_value,custom_field_6_value,custom_field_7_value,custom_field_8_value,custom_field_9_value,custom_field_10_value,verify_age,phppos_items_ibfk_7,item_inactive_index,tags,full_search,name_search,item_number_search,product_id_search,description_search,size_search,custom_field_1_value_search,custom_field_2_value_search,custom_field_3_value_search,custom_field_4_value_search,custom_field_5_value_search,custom_field_6_value_search,custom_field_7_value_search,custom_field_8_value_search,custom_field_9_value_search,custom_field_10_value_search | deleted                 | 4       | const                                   | 21188 |     9.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | inv                             | NULL       | ref    | phppos_inventory_ibfk_1,location_id,phppos_inventory_custom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | phppos_inventory_custom | 8       | pos.phppos_items.item_id,const          |     3 |   100.00 | NULL                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_location_items           | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_location_items_ibfk_2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                 | 8       | const,pos.phppos_items.item_id          |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_item_variations          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_item_variations_ibfk_1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | PRIMARY                 | 4       | pos.inv.item_variation_id               |     1 |   100.00 | Using where                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_location_item_variations | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_item_attribute_location_values_ibfk_2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                 | 8       | pos.phppos_item_variations.id,const     |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_suppliers                | NULL       | ref    | person_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | person_id               | 4       | pos.phppos_items.supplier_id            |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_categories               | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | PRIMARY                 | 4       | pos.phppos_items.category_id            |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                               |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | inv1                            | NULL       | ref    | phppos_inventory_ibfk_1,location_id,trans_date,phppos_inventory_ibfk_4,phppos_inventory_custom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | phppos_inventory_custom | 8       | pos.inv.trans_items,pos.inv.location_id |     3 |    50.00 | Using where; Using index           |
+----+--------------------+---------------------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Explain maria db:

```
+------+---------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table                           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                  | key                     | key_len | ref                                                           | rows  | Extra                    |
+------+--------------------+---------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_items                    | ref    | PRIMARY,deleted,deleted_system_item                                                            | deleted                 | 4       | const                                                         | 23955 | Using where              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | inv                             | ref    | phppos_inventory_ibfk_1,location_id,phppos_inventory_custom                                    | phppos_inventory_ibfk_1 | 4       | freelance_pos5.phppos_items.item_id                           |     2 | Using where              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_location_items           | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_location_items_ibfk_2                                                           | PRIMARY                 | 8       | const,freelance_pos5.phppos_items.item_id                     |     1 |                          |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_item_variations          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_item_variations_ibfk_1                                                          | PRIMARY                 | 4       | freelance_pos5.inv.item_variation_id                          |     1 | Using where              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_location_item_variations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,phppos_item_attribute_location_values_ibfk_2                                           | PRIMARY                 | 8       | freelance_pos5.phppos_item_variations.id,const                |     1 | Using where              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_suppliers                | ref    | person_id                                                                                      | person_id               | 4       | freelance_pos5.phppos_items.supplier_id                       |     1 | Using where              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | phppos_categories               | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                        | PRIMARY                 | 4       | freelance_pos5.phppos_items.category_id                       |     1 | Using where              |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | inv1                            | ref    | phppos_inventory_ibfk_1,location_id,trans_date,phppos_inventory_ibfk_4,phppos_inventory_custom | phppos_inventory_custom | 8       | freelance_pos5.inv.trans_items,freelance_pos5.inv.location_id |     2 | Using where; Using index |
+------+--------------------+---------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Tables described (Reached StackOverflow char limit)

https://pastebin.com/nhngSHb8

Create tables:

https://pastebin.com/aWMeriqt

MYSQL (DEV BOX)

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%';
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                            | Value |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0     |
| Threads_cached                           | 4     |
| Threads_connected                        | 1     |
| Threads_created                          | 5     |
| Threads_running                          | 1     |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

MARIA DB

```
MariaDB [freelance_pos5]> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%';
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                            | Value |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0     |
| Threadpool_idle_threads                  | 0     |
| Threadpool_threads                       | 0     |
| Threads_cached                           | 3     |
| Threads_connected                        | 2     |
| Threads_created                          | 5     |
| Threads_running                          | 1     |
| wsrep_applier_thread_count               | 0     |
| wsrep_rollbacker_thread_count            | 0     |
| wsrep_thread_count                       | 0     |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your query is wrong. The filtering predicate `AND phppos_items.system_item = 0` defeats the outer join, effectively converting it into an inner join. The same can be said about the next two predicates. Fix this first, then we can optimize it.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is a bit easier to read the index order compared to `DESCRIBE` (can be less text too). Interesting `delete` was chosen as the index rather than `deleted_system_item` because I assume the naming is the order. Sound like you have a "use MariaDB" as solution :-) BTW, which mariadb version? You have a limit without an `ORDER`? Intentional someone told me that the GROUP being the default order was deprecated.

Comment: Maria db 10.2.31

Comment: Could your post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; from MySQL and MariaDB servers?  Should the data type and (length) of each side of the JOIN lft = rgt be the same in the DESCRIBE of the tables? There are a few not the same.

Comment: Added results show global status

Comment: The thread info from each server looks reasonable.  It appears MariaDB is not a production server as well.

Comment: Just for fun, after you run on the MySQL, put a SHOW WARNINGS; immediately after your query, on the same line, following the queries ; - please so it runs in the same SESSION.

Comment: Warning | 3127 | Query block name `subq` is not found for SEMIJOIN hint

Comment: Apparently the MySQL version does not have this HINT feature available.  Wishing you the best. I hope one day to provide tuning services for you again.

Comment: Even if I remove that from query maraidb is still fast

Comment: STATUS is not useful without VARIABLES.

Comment: Why the "threads"?  There will be only one "thread" running the query.

Comment: @TheImpaler - In MySQL `INNER` and `OUTER` are ignored and have no impact.  `LEFT` is ignored when the Optimizer can see that it is really a plain `JOIN`.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I agree that the engine will silently do that. The point is the query may be misleading to the OP. He may think he's getting one result, but he's actually getting something else.

Comment: @TheImpaler - I see your point.  You are recommending fixing INNER and/or OUTER to use them correctly.  I am suggesting that _removing_ them avoids the issue.

Comment: @ChrisMuench You may need to dig deeper with Query Profiler.  Outline is in this URL - https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/query-profiling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the

```
WHERE inv.trans_id = (SELECT Max(inv1.trans_id)
```

into the INNER JOIN is the game changer.

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT inv1.trans_items, inv1.item_variation_id, inv1.location_id, MAX(inv1.trans_id) as trans_id
        FROM phppos_inventory inv1
        WHERE inv1.trans_date < '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY inv1.trans_items, inv1.item_variation_id, inv1.location_id
    ORDER BY inv1.trans_items, inv1.item_variation_id, inv1.location_id
) inv1 on inv1.trans_id = inv.trans_id
    AND inv1.trans_items = inv.trans_items 
    AND (inv1.item_variation_id = phppos_item_variations.id OR phppos_item_variations.id IS NULL) 
    AND inv1.location_id = inv.location_id
```

The execution is reduced from 80+s down to ~ <0.4s, on MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB's and MySQL's Optimizers started diverging significantly at 5.6.  Certain queries will run queries faster in one than the other.

I think I see a way to speed up the query, perhaps on both versions.

- Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when it is the same as `JOIN`, which seems to be the case for at least `phppos_items`, which has items in the `WHERE` that override `LEFT`.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; meanwhile, I will guess that what indexes you have/don't have, and that each table has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`
- Use composite indexes where appropriate.  (More below.)
- Get the 20 rows *before* `JOINing` to the rest of the tables:

  ```
  SELECT ...
      FROM ( SELECT inv.id, pi.id
              FROM  `phppos_inventory` AS inv `inv`
              JOIN  `phppos_items` AS pi
                   ON pi.`item_id` = `inv`.`trans_items`
                AND  inv.location_id IN( 1 )
                AND  pi.`system_item` = 0
                AND  pi.`deleted` = 0
                AND  `is_service` != 1   -- Which table is this in???
              GROUP BY  pi.`item_id`
              LIMIT  20 )
      LEFT JOIN .... (( all the other tables ))
      -- no GROUP BY or LIMIT needed (I think)

  phppos_items:  INDEX(item_id, deleted, system_item, is_service)
  phppos_items:  INDEX(deleted, system_item, is_service)
  phppos_inventory:  INDEX(trans_items, location_id, location_id, item_variation_id, trans_date, trans_id)
  phppos_inventory:  INDEX(location_id)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Aside with the fact that the query is misleading since the outer join is discarded, the main difference is that the second engine operation in MariabDB is an *index range scan* (`ref`) using the `phppos_inventory_custom` index. MySQL also chose an *index range scan* but over `phppos_inventory_ibfk_1`.

However, without the definition of these two indexes it's difficult to asses why the engines may have chosen a different path.

Please add to your question the definition of these indexes, and alse their selectivity (percent of estimated rows selected / total table rows) to elaborate more.

Comment: Create tables https://pastebin.com/aWMeriqt. phppos_items is about 3k and phppos_inventory table is 170k